# Cloning a git repo with all submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-push, git-clone

I have a working git repository containing several submodules (obtained by cloning different repositories).

Now, I want to **copy the whole repository (with all the submodules)** to a bare git repo on a different machine by either using pushing or cloning. I'm fine loosing the history of the submodules (I'm just interested in keeping their content).

Is this possible ? In my attempts, in the cloned repository the submodule directory is empty.

P.S. I know that this is not the correct workflow (see [creating a public repo with submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811514/creating-a-public-repo-with-submodules)), however there is no possibility of updating the original submodule.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can clone the git repo with all submodule using `recursive` as follow:

```
git clone --recursive your-repo-url
```

on the other hand if you have already cloned, you can use:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

You won't lose any history in your submodule

Answer (score 3):

> in the cloned repository the submodule directory is empty.

If, by "cloned repo", you are referring to the bare repo, it is normal: a bare repo is always empty.

If you are alluding to a clone of the bare repo, you need to add:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

That way, you will see the content of those submodules.

---

Remember, a submodule is:

- a declaration in a `.gitmodules` file
- a [gitlink entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) (special entry recording the SHA1 of that submodule)

So all you need to do is clone that repo (even with a `--recursive` option), and the submodules will follow.